# Spring cloud stream kafka binder to create consumer with on demand configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE and Spring cloud Edgware.RELEASE across the Microservices.

I've bound a consumer using `@EnableBinding` annotation. The annotation will do rest of the part for me to consume events.

Some requirements came up to configure the topic name and some other configuration properties manually for which I want to override some of the properties of a consumer defined in an application.properties at application boot time.

Is there any direct way to do such?

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit? Are you trying to re-configure something that has already been configured using property mechanism?

Comment: I have a Microservice M1 and at the startup of M1, I am fetching Kafka topic name from another Microservice M2. Thereafter I need to use this topic to consume events.

Comment: There is an [open issue to add programmatic binding](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/954).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an initialization bean, it can do the work:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDataDemoApplication {

    @Bean
    InitializingBean populateDatabase() {
        return () -> {
            // doWhatYouWantHere...
        };
}
```

Comment: I need to take a configuration by making an external call and provide the same to launch Kafka consumer, At the time of initialization of a bean is not possible because the dependencies to make an external call possibly in progress to come up.  Anyway, I am through with a workaround for the problem.